# Azure DevOps conditional initialization of variables is not working

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I am quite new in Yaml and AzureDevOps and I am trying to initialize variable based on condition

```
variables:
- name: DisplayName
  ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'wh') }}:
    value: 'DisplayNAME-WH'
  ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'lw') }}:
    value: 'DisplayNAME-LW'
```

Where my *'env'* is variable passed via UI in Azure DevOps[image]

Issue what I am getting that "DisplayName" stays still empty (is not initialized).

Can you help me out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps conditional initialization of variables is not working

According to the [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax):

> In a pipeline, template expression variables (`${{ variables.var }}`)
> get processed **at compile time**, before runtime starts. Macro syntax
> variables (`$(var)`) get processed **during runtime** before a task runs.

So, we could not use the `$(env)` in the `${{ if eq('$(env)', 'wh') }}`. That because the syntax of `${{ if eq('$(env)', 'wh') }}` is parsed before the syntax of $(env).

To resolve this issue, we could to defined the variable as [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script):

```
parameters:
- name: 'env'
  default: 'wh'
  type: string
  values:
    - wh
    - lw

variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'wh') }}: 
    DisplayName: 'DisplayNAME-WH'
  ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'lw') }}: 
    DisplayName: 'DisplayNAME-LW'

steps:
- script: 
   echo $(DisplayName)
```

The test result:

[image]